# Create Theme Problem with navigation bar e tab bar

Tags: swift

I have created this structure to be able to modify the application time. it works on all the elements drawn for navigation bar and tab bar. I have tried several things but it does not work, someone can point out to me a few suggestions. Thank you

through a swith I can make the values change to all elements except as said to the navigation bar and tab bar.

structure:

```
theme file
ThemeProtocol file
```

then theme file

```
 dark
 Default
```

File Theme

```
import UIKit

class Theme {

    static  var current: ThemeProtocol = Default()

}
```

File ThemeProtocol

```
import UIKit

protocol ThemeProtocol {

    var backgroundColorView: UIColor { get }
    var tint: UIColor { get }
    var coloreTesto: UIColor { get }
    var coloreTabella: UIColor { get }
    var colorecella: UIColor { get }
    var coloreLineaTabella: UIColor { get }
    var coloreTestoBottone: UIColor { get }
}

file Dark e Default
import UIKit

class Dark: ThemeProtocol {

    var backgroundColorView: UIColor = UIColor.black
    var tint: UIColor = UIColor.blue
    var coloreTesto: UIColor = UIColor.white
    var coloreTabella: UIColor = UIColor.black
    var colorecella: UIColor = UIColor.black
    var coloreLineaTabella: UIColor = UIColor.white
    var coloreTestoBottone: UIColor = UIColor.white

}
```

for example if I put this code in the files I put in the viewDidLoad every time I click on the swicth the color changes but I can not do it on the navigation and tab bar

```
override func viewDidLoad () {
         super.viewDidLoad ()
         view.backgroundColor = Theme.current.backgroundColorView
     }
```

Comment: Please indent your code by 4 positions to improve formatting

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use: `navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = <Your color>`.

I've put up a sample, but used a framework. But my sample should give you a solution. You can find the sample here: https://github.com/enigmatic7earth/theme-sample